# Unable to install NVIDIA GeForce 8700M GT driver on Windows XP laptop

Tags: laptop, drivers, graphics-card

I am trying to install an NVIDIA GeForce 8700M GT driver on a laptop running Windows XP Home Edition SP3. However when I try to install the driver I unfortunately get an error as pictured below:

[image]

How can I install it successfully?

Comment: Are you sure the card is in, and that it is the right device?

Comment: yes this is a laptop. it is also dual booted with windows 7. The card works in windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [link for the specs on the 285.58 driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/winxp-285.58-whql-driver.html).  If you click on "supported product" and go down to the section entitled "GeForce 8 series", you'll see that the 8700's are not listed as supported by this driver.

Go to [www.nvidia.com](http://www.nvidia.com), click on "Download Drivers" and enter the following options:

- Product Type: GeForce
- Product Series: GeForce 8M Series (Notebooks)
- Product: GeForce 8700M GT
- Operating System: Windows XP

You should be taken to the [page for the 266.58 driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook-winxp-266.58-whql-driver.html).  That one should work for you.

The 266.58 driver page does have a note about "Notebooks supporting Hybrid Power technology with Intel chipsets are not supported by this release."  Not sure if that applies to you or not, but there has to be some reason that this driver isn't working with your hardware.

Here's a [link to the model content page](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=DL&os=&category=&moid=1854872&rpn=PSPB9U&modelFilter=X205-S7483&selCategory=2756709&selFamily=1073768663) for your model Toshiba Satellite.  If you click on Downloads, and then refine on a category of "Display", you'll see that they only have drivers for Vista and Windows 7.  Now that doesn't mean that there's no hope, but I have a feeling that it's going take some digging (Google) to find the right driver for you.

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: Hmm...it seems that you still don't have the correct driver.  Is this a Sony Vaio, by chance?  Or are you using 64-bit Windows XP?

Comment: No I am using 32 bit. It is a toshiba satellite x205-s7438.

Comment: @wardedmocha made an edit with some more info; hope it helps.

Comment: I do have an Intel chip set